# Why is this equality correct? Question involving complex number, conjugate, innerproduct

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $b_i, b_j \in \mathbb{C}$.
I am wondering why $\langle b_i, b_j \rangle\overline{\langle b_i, b_j \rangle}=\mid\langle b_i,b_j\rangle\mid^2$.

Why is the product of the these two innerproducts equal to the modulus of the innerproduct squared?

I was thinking like this: if i ignore the innerproduct and pretend it is just a random complex number, then I understand how we got a modulus involved, because the product of a complex number with its complex conjugate is defined as the modulus of the complex number, I assume. But I don't understand the square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"the product of a complex number with its complex conjugate is defined as the modulus of the complex number": no, it is the square of the modulus.

Comment: Ok, this explains my misunderstanding,  thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is true for any complex number $z$ : $z \bar{z} = |z|^2$. Indeed, if you note $z = x + iy$, you have $z \bar{z} = (x + iy) (x - iy) = (x)^2 - (iy)^2 = x^2 + y^2 = |z|^2$.